# Wiring a new dimmer switch

Tags: wiring, lighting

I am installing a new single pole dimmer/rocker switch which has a ground, neutral, line and load connections. The old toggle switch has only one Romex cable coming into the switch box with only one hot, one neutral and a ground. Can I use this rocker /dimmer switch or do I need to purchase another switch.

Comment: The old switch *does not* have a neutral. It is an old-school "switch loop" and the white wire is supply hot.   There is no neutral.  In the 2000s code was changed to require white wires used that way to be marked with black tape etc.  In 2011 the rule was changed prohibiting this and requiring neutral to the switch (using /3 cable). That is to support switches like yours.

Answer (score 1):

If only one cable then you have a hot(white) and a switched hot(black), no neutral.

If the instructions for that dimmer require neutral(white) then you need another switch that does not require neutral or need to run a new cable to the light. A cable that has black, red, white plus ground, a /3 cable, ground is given to be in it.

Neutral must be white, but white does not always mean neutral.

Comment: Ok - thank you for responding  - appreciate it. I thought when using a hot white you were supposed to mark it somehow.

Comment: @Paul  You are correct. When using a switch loop, the always hot , white wire, should, by code, be marked, usually by black tape, at the beginning and end. However, in the real world, it's not always done because of ignorance.

Comment: Yes - the home builder for this subdivision got quite a few things wrong.